# анализ и обработка текста

Tags: c, алгоритм, синтаксический-анализ, анализ

Доброго времени суток =)

Задача такова:

Дан текстовый файл, найти в нем все числительные и посчитать количество, соответствующее каждой цифре.

## Например:

"сорок пять" - 40 и 5;

"сто" - только 100;

"двадцатый" - 20;

"двадцать два" - 20 и 2;

"сто семьдесят вторым" - 100, 70, 2;

---

итого:
100 - 2 раза
70  - 1
40  - 1
20  - 2
2   - 2

================================================

реализовать нужно на си, но не суть.

прошу направить в нужное русло, подсказать, какие методы и алгоритмы использовать, т.к. даже не знаю с чего начать...

есть мысль создавать словарь соответствий, и уже по словарю сравнивать, но почему то мне кажется, что такой подход не правильный.

с благодарностью...

Comment: Видимо искать надо не числители, а *числительные*.

Comment: верно, просто в русском не силен... (потрібно шукати числівники)

Comment: ИМХО, трудно придумать менее подходящий для такой задачи язык, чем C (если имеется в виду именно С, а не плюсы)

Comment: @andy.37, это сильно зависит от уровня компетенции (знание языка и его библиотек) и количества собственных наработок. (IMHO для серьезных вещей (не данная задача) как раз С++ не лучший выбор).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, какой-то словарь все равно потребуется.

Другой вопрос, что проще:

- найти словарь со всеми *словоформами* (т.е. с правильными суффиксами и окончаниями) *числительных*;
- руками вбить все что может потребоваться в такой словарь;
- сгенерить его (в соответствии с правилами языка) из краткого словаря числительных в единственном числе именительного падежа;
- или искать похожие слова в кратком словаре и проверять, можно ли на основе словаря и правил словообразования получить проверяемое слово.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо словаря есть еще проблема обработки таких вещей, как, например, *двадцать пять тысяч* - это должно быть 20, 5 и 1000 или все же 25000?

Словарь, пожалуй, проще составить найти или составить, потому что правила обработки будут иметь исключений больше, чем правил :)